# How to Get Raspberry Pi IP Address And Host Name Using C#

Tags: c#, ip, raspberry-pi, hostname

I'm using raspbian in my raspberry pi and I assign a static ip address to it. Now I want to get its ip address and host name from a C# application. I found a code to get all ip addresses in the network and I'm unable to get its host name.

Can anyone please point out how to get the hostname of a raspberry pi by providing its ipaddress or any different method.

A soon reply is more appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Once you have IP you can call [GetHostEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143997(v=vs.110).aspx) with ip argument and look for HostName of returned IPHostEntry.

Comment: I tried it,`IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress);`
`hostName = hostEntry.HostName;` but it gives me an error no such host is known

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/156638